# Magento Event On Any Page Load

Tags: magento

I am wondering if there is an event that is fired once every time a page is loaded before rendering to html in magento?

This might be useful if you want to do some business logic for semi-static attributes that don't rely on user sessions.

For example I will be using this to deliver the canonical tag to the header of magento.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There are *several* request-related events which are dispatched for most page-/content-generating requests. Below is a partial list in processing order of some useful ones, and I expect others may comment on this post with some others. Many of these are not suitable for your need (I've noted in bold below where you should begin considering). There are also a few block-instantiation-related events which, although they *could* be observed for your purpose, are generic to every block and really aren't appropriate.

- The first practical singly-fired event is [`controller_front_init_before`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php#L128). This event is dispatched in Front Controller initialization in response to all dispatched requests. Because it is dispatched before the action controllers are invoked, only global-area observers will be able to observe this event.
- Assuming the request is routed from the Front Controller through the routers to an action controller, there are some [events which can be observed prior to rendering in `preDispatch()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php#L528) - note the generic `controller_action_predispatch` event handle which could be consumed for all events vs the two dynamic event handles:

  ```
  Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_action_predispatch', array('controller_action' => $this));
  Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_action_predispatch_' . $this->getRequest()->getRouteName(),
      array('controller_action' => $this));
  Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_action_predispatch_' . $this->getFullActionName(),
      array('controller_action' => $this));
  ```
- How a response is being rendered may affect the events available; the main variations would come from whether or not layout updates are being used to render the response (and how). For example, [`core_layout_update_updates_get_after`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php#L419) could be used to inject a layout update file to the list of configured module layout update files (a rare but potentially useful case). The controller actions are closely coupled with the layout modeling, so there are a few events which could work:

  - [`controller_action_layout_load_before`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php#L300)
  - [`controller_action_layout_generate_xml_before`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php#L318)
  - [`controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_before`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php#L337) and [`controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php#L349) - **the latter of which would be the first applicable to your needs**

Assuming that `renderLayout()` is being used in all actions about which you care, there are two events (one generic and one route-specific) [which it dispatches](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php#L384):

```
    Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_action_layout_render_before');
    Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_action_layout_render_before_'.$this->getFullActionName());
```

After all of the routing, dispatching, view configuring, block instantiating, and rendering are done, there is one last-ditch event which is dispatched by the Front Controller before the response is sent: [`controller_front_send_response_before`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php#L186). This event is not suitable for your need, but it's a nice bookend to the `controller_front_init_before` event which began this answer.

Comment: I used controller_front_init_before and it appears to be triggered once per page load. I will do some additional testing and report back.

Comment: @ajameswolf That event is *very* early, and your block instance will not exist.

Comment: Yep I realized that it was too soon and also did not allow access to the layout object. controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after works perfectly so far. The object contains the layout object so I don't have to do Mage::app->getLayout etc.

For anyone interested I am going to also post a bit of code for better understanding of what I was trying to accomplish. I am sure there are other uses for this. Right now Im in SEO mode so Dynamic Title Tags, Descriptions , Title Tag Suffix/Prefix, Redirects.. Just a few off the top of my head.

Comment: public function test($observer){
        $_head = $observer->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
        $_url_parts = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        $_canonical_url = $_current_url =  "http://".$_url_parts['host'].$_url_parts['path'];
        $_canonical_url = 'my different url than current';
        $_head->removeItem('link_rel', $_current_url);
        $_head->addLinkRel('canonical',$_canonical_url);
       // echo "<pre>";
       // var_dump($observer->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->getData());
       // echo "<pre>";
        return $observer;
    }

Comment: controller_action_layout_render_before--- This event solves my problem. This will load only once per page.. I have the same requirement and used this event and it works.. Thank u @benmarks

Answer (score 3):

http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/  this will help.

`app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php`  this event

`controller_action_layout_load_before`

is fired

`app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php` event

```
core_block_abstract_to_html_before
```

above two events might be of help.

Comment: to add to @benmarks, 'core_block_abstract_to_html_before' is not suitable because it is called for every block before its rendered, so it will called multiple times every page (times = blocks count on the given page)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this event `controller_action_layout_render_before_RouteName_ControllerName_ActionName`

you can also log all the events which are fired on any page load from `Mage` class in below function

```
public static function dispatchEvent($name, array $data = array())
    {
        Mage::log($name);
        Varien_Profiler::start('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
        $result = self::app()->dispatchEvent($name, $data);
        Varien_Profiler::stop('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: This is useful amit, however In this example the controller name is not relevant as I would want to catch the event regardless of what controller is handling the request. E.g every page load.

Answer (score 1):

We can use controller_front_init_routers event using observer. In that observer method,you can get request object as follows.

`$request = $observer->getEvent()->getData('front')->getRequest();`

Comment: I've not checked this but thank you. It would be more appropriate in the comments section once you have that ability.