# Error in checkout - AddBodyClass

Tags: xml, magento, layout, checkout

I added the following in my local.xml to add an extra body class when a customer is logged in:

```
<customer_logged_in>
<reference name="root">
  <action method="addBodyClass">
    <classname>logged-in</classname>
  </action>
</reference>
</customer_logged_in>
```

This works, but when I go to the onepage checkout, I get the following error:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:98:"Invalid method Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Progress::addBodyClass(Array
(
[0] => logged-in
)
)";i:1;s:1967:"#0 [internal function]: Varien_Object->__call('addBodyClass', Array)
#1 [internal function]: Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Progress->addBodyClass('logged-in')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

cameronhimself makes a very good point about the assumption that the root block is of `Mage_Page_Block_Html` inheritance. I made the very same assumption that you did, my code was identical! I was also finding this was breaking some checkout related logic (strictly speaking it was breaking AJAX logic that didn't use `Mage_Page_Block_Html` as the root block).

However, as an improvement to cameronhimselfs answer, it is actually very easy to add body classes via an observer without observing `core_block_abstract_to_html_before`. Only catch is you need a module for it. So you either need to make one for this purpose or use an existing one that makes sense. Then, preferably, we'd like to hook into an event that is triggered once per page load *always*.

Well, there are such events. benmarks provided a very nice and succinct [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15617264/733347) that gives us some hints. From that, you can see that good event could be `controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after`.

So by observing the event as usual:

```
<controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after>
    <observers>
        <tghpcore_controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>yourmodule/observer</class>
            <method>addBodyClasses</method>
        </tghpcore_controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after>
    </observers>
</controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after>
```

You can cleanly and safely achieve the same end within your observer class:

```
public function addBodyClasses($observer)
{
    /** @var $layout Mage_Core_Model_Layout */
    $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
    // Retrieve the root block
    $root = $layout->getBlock('root');
    // Be 100% sure that there is a root block
    if($root) {
        // Check that the root block is a Magento page block that we can add body classes to
        if(is_a($root, 'Mage_Page_Block_Html')) {
            // Add logged in/out body classes
            if(Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()) {
                $root->addBodyClass('logged-in');
            } else {
                $root->addBodyClass('logged-out');
            }
            // You can even add more conditions and body classes for whatever you may want here
        }
    }
}
```

Worked very nicely for me. Hope it does for you too!

Comment: Thanks!
Created my own module using your example and works perfectly now.

Answer (score 5):

Your layout update assumes that all "root" blocks inherit from `Mage_Page_Block_Html`, the class with the `addBodyClass()` method. Unfortunately, this is not the case. I don't think there's a simple workaround.

You might be able to accomplish what you're trying to do by creating an observer and hooking the `core_block_abstract_to_html_before` event. From there you can check if the customer is logged in, retrieve the block being rendered, and call `addBodyClass()` on it after checking that it has the method (or inside a try block). This is probably pretty costly, though, as it will be called many times per page load--once for each block.

As a hack, you could override the `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract` class and copy the `addBodyClass()` method to it. This should work, but it's considered poor practice because it *will* conflict with any other modules that try to override `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, managed to fix it by creating my own module using your logic (and the example below)