# Magento show my model's public function

Tags: php, magento, authentication

I want to run a public function 'always' in the frontend.

So I've got in community/Myname/Forcelogin/etc/config.xml:

```
<config>    
    <modules>
        <Myname_Forcelogin><version>0.1.0</version></Myname_Forcelogin>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <check_login>
                <class>Myname_Forcelogin_Model</class>
            </check_login>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

In community/Myname/Forcelogin/Model/Forcelogin.php:

```
class Myname_Forcelogin_Model_Forcelogin
{
    public function check_login()
    {
        die('Hello there');
    }
}
```

So what should I add/change to have the "check_login()" *always* run in the frontend?

Comment: What do you mean by 'always run in the frontend'? You want your function to be called for every frontend page? If so, do you want it before something is rendered, or after?

Comment: please tell us in detail

Answer (score 1):

Im not entirely sure what your question is but if i understand correctly you want ***every*** page to ***instantiate*** your model and run this method? you may want to look into having an event listener that runs this method for you, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616489/magento-event-on-any-page-load) for an idea of what events to use.

**EDIT**

change your `config.xml` to look like this

```
<config>    
    <modules>
        <Myname_Forcelogin><version>0.1.0</version></Myname_Forcelogin>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <check_login>
                <class>Myname_Forcelogin_Model</class>
            </check_login>
        </models>
        <events>
            <controller_action_layout_load_before>
                <observers>
                    <checklogin><!-- this tags name does not matter, so long as it is all lower case and unique -->
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class><!-- the class alias of the listening model --></class>
                        <method><!-- the method to be called on that model --></method>
                    </checklogin>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_layout_load_before>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

for more details follow [this](http://blogs.ifuelinteractive.com/2010/08/18/module-magento-event/) link

Comment: Hi Nanos, thanks for your answer. This is very helpful. I now know that I would like to run mys script as an extension of controller_action_layout_load_before. But I don't understand how to actually fire my public function.

Comment: @bvl Magento has a built in observer pattern that allows you to do things like this, a few google searches should pull it up really pretty easily but the basics are that you can create a model in such a way that a given method will execute, first you need to edit your config to include the `<events>` section and fill that in [as shown here](http://blogs.ifuelinteractive.com/2010/08/18/module-magento-event/) i will update my answer shortly