# Overriding CsMarketplace account controller with a custom controller

Tags: magento, plugins, controller, magento-1.9

I've seen lots of code available to override core Magento files, but not any Magento plugin files.

I have installed the CsMarketplace plugin to my website for vendor management, and I want to override the vendor - register function to write my custom code which needs to work just after vendor is successfully registered.

I Need to override: function `createPostAction();`
in file `mypoject/app/code/local/Ced/CsMarketplace/controllers/AccountController.php`

File 1: `mypoject/app/code/local/Core/Ced/CsMarketplace/controllers/AccountController.php`

```
require_once 'app/code/local/Ced/CsMarketplace/controllers/AccountController.php';

class Core_Ced_CsMarketplace_AccountController extends Ced_CsMarketplace_Controller_AbstractController {

/**
 * Create customer account action
 */
  public function createPostAction() {
    //my custom code
  }
}
```

File 2: `mypoject/app/code/local/Core/Ced/CsMarketplace/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Core_Ced_CsMarketplace>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </Core_Ced_CsMarketplace>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <CsMarketplace>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Core_Ced_CsMarketplace before="Ced_CsMarketplace">Core_Ced_CsMarketplace</Core_Ced_CsMarketplace>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </CsMarketplace>
    </routers>
</frontend>
</config>
```

File 3: `mypoject/app/etc/modules/Core_All.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
 <modules>
    <Core_Customer>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Core_Customer>
    <Core_Ced_CsMarketplace>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Core_Ced_CsMarketplace>
</modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your controller is incorrectly placed in the filesystem. Magento always assumes that controllers located *somewhere* under a `controllers` directory which is itself exactly inside just a Namespace + Modulename folder, e.g.

```
app/code/[codepool]/[Namespace]/[Modulename]/controllers/ # I previously missed the codepool, because Magento 2 :-)
```

You are trying to get the system to locate controllers in a location where it by design cannot locate them.

(edit based on OP comment)

Controllers need ***two*** levels of depth (namespace + module name). The following won't work:

```
app/code/local/Namespace/controllers
app/code/local/Namespace/Modulename/SomeOtherFolder/controllers
```

In your case, you may choose `CustomCed` as your namespace, giving:

```
app/code/local/CustomCsd/CsMarketplace/controllers/AccountController.php
```

In there you will override `createPostAction()`.

Also, depending on what you are doing, you could possibly use [one of the dynamic events which exist around controller action dispatching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15617264/833795).

Comment: i created a file as per your reply - app/code/custom/Ced/controllers/AccountController.php but unfortunately it did not worked. This plugin already have two sections called CsMarketplace & CsVendorPanel created at this path - app/code/local/Ced/ (may be this information can help) and i need to override only controller of CsMarketplace

Comment: @do_do_do Do you find any solution for it, Personally I am looking for a good Marketplace extension in magento, this module look nice but have limitation, Please let me know if you find any good solution..... Thanks